# How to get querystring value after MVC routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm guessing my approach is wrong, which is why my research produced little results

My website was using querystrings, and within my HtmlHelper class I could get the query string with the following code

When you start MVC4, the defulat route lets you pass an ID as a querystring. The routing engine 'converts' this from a querystring into part of the URL
How do I then query this value?

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkWithQueryString(this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText, string action, string controllerName, object routeValues)
{
    var queryString = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
    ...
```

The above works fine.

However, I'm now using the routing engine. When you first start with MVC, you get the ID parameter set up for you, and when you perform a search similar to `www.mysite.com/?id=HelloWorld` the routing engine 'converts' or 'translates' this into a URL , such as `www.mysite.com/HelloWorld`

The issue is, I still need to get that value - the HelloWorld value.

Using the code above always returns an empty list because there is no querystring!

I know I can just read the URL, split by forward slash and then get the item out of the array but, I'm hoping there is a more elegant way.

The real reason for this is due to pagination. What is happening is my URL is `www.mysite.com/products/shoes/12`

I then click on next page and it loses the values, showing me `www.mysite.com/products/10` (where 10 is the starting index). Obviously I need the URL to be `www.mysite.com/products/10/shoes/12`

How do I get the value HelloWorld (ID parameter) from the URL?

Comment: The URL you want is invalid. Did you mean: `www.mysite.com?id=HelloWorld`? Why do you want the original querystring anyway? MVC's binding will pass the querystring parameter values to any controller parameters of the same name (eg `Index(string id)` or `Get(string id)`). What is your controller method's definition? How did you define the routing?

Comment: Corrected, thanks. The problem is an extension method, adding the function to the `@Html` razor syntax. Therefore it executes outside of the controller. I updated my post to explain why

Comment: How are you using the method? Where is the rest of the code? If the method returns an `<a href="HelloWorld"/>`, there is no conversion at all. This *is* equivalent to `www.mysite.com/HelloWorld`. Anyway, this is still about routing - you should define a route that includes product Id and page number and add a controller method that accepts both these parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from route values:

```
object id = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
```